# GraphQL, how do I send a query that has a list?

Tags: graphql

So I know how to return a list of results in the query, but I'm not sure how I send in multiple items to then get back multiple results?

One result:

```
         query {
              getInventory(sku: "123456-$25"){
                  price
                  quantity
              }
         }
```

Multiple results:

```
         query {
              getInventory(sku: "123456-$25", sku: "654321-$10"){   -- how do I send in a list here?
                  inventory {
                     price
                     quantity
                   }
              }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the `getInventory` field would need to support an argument thats an array of strings.

In SDL form:

```
type Query {
  getInventory(skus: [String!]): SomeReturnType
}
```

Then you'd query it like this:

```
query {
  getInventory(skus: ["123456-$25", "654321-$10"]) {
    // whatever your selections are
  }
}
```

**Note:**
Be careful with `[String!]` structure:

```
skus: null // valid
skus: [] // valid
skus: ['a', 'b'] // valid
skus: ['a', null, 'b'] // error
```